# Generic constructor reference and static method in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics

Please, consider the following code:

```
class Wrapper<T> {

    public static forConstructor<S extends Object>(construc: { new (...args: any[]): S }): Wrapper<S> {
        return new Wrapper<S>();
    }
}

class A {
    private aaa: string = null;
}

class B {
    private bbb: string = null;
}

const wrapper: Wrapper<A> = Wrapper.forConstructor(B);// LINE X
```

At LINE X `Wrapper<A> = Wrapper<B>` that is an wrong, however, TypeScript doesn't show error at this line. What is my mistake?

Comment: Currently `Wrapper<A>` and `Wrapper<B>` are structurally compatible. If you'll store the passed constructor as a field (for example) you'll get an error

Comment: @AlekseyL. I modified fields, added different methods, constructors - didn't help.

Comment: I'm talking about wrapper. I'll add an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `Wrapper<A>` and `Wrapper<B>` are structurally compatible. If you'll store the passed constructor as a field (for example) you'll get an error:

```
type Constructor<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T;

class Wrapper<T> {
    constructor(private c: Constructor<T>){}

    public static forConstructor<T>(construc: Constructor<T>): Wrapper<T> {
        return new Wrapper<T>(construc);
    }
}

class A {
    private aaa: string = null;
}

class B {
    private bbb: string = null;
}

const wrapper: Wrapper<A> = Wrapper.forConstructor(B); // error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20Constructor%3CT%3E%20%3D%20new%20(...args%3A%20any%5B%5D)%20%3D%3E%20T%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Wrapper%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(private%20c%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E)%7B%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20static%20forConstructor%3CT%3E(construc%3A%20Constructor%3CT%3E)%3A%20Wrapper%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Wrapper%3CT%3E(construc)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20aaa%3A%20string%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20private%20bbb%3A%20string%20%3D%20null%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20wrapper%3A%20Wrapper%3CA%3E%20%3D%20Wrapper.forConstructor(B)%3B%20%2F%2F%20error)

Answer (score 0):

A static method can not use the instance type argument `Wrapper<T>` since static is not instance bounded. Your method signature `<S extends Object` essentially means `any` Object. So there is no type safety at all. That's why the tscompiler does not complain at

```
const wrapper: Wrapper<A> = Wrapper.forConstructor(B);// LINE X
```

However if you actually use the instance type argument and make it non-static then it will complain e.g.

```
class Wrapper<S> {

    public forConstructor(construc: { new (...args: any[]): S }): Wrapper<S> {
        return new Wrapper<S>();
    }
}

const wrapper: Wrapper<A> = new Wrapper();
wrapper.forConstructor(B); // will not work
```

Comment: `A static method can not use the instance type argument Wrapper<T> since static is not instance bounded.` sure, I know it. That's why generic parameter for class is `T`, but for static method is `S`. And I need only static method. Is it possible to do?

Comment: You can not use `Wrapper<T>` as `T` in your static method. So, no it is not possible.